# Installed a package on command line and can import it via command line. Receive ModuleNotFoundError when importing in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I installed the python package `lifelines` on my terminal. The windows terminal is my terminal of choice, with a powershell and anaconda terminal that I often used.

I tried installing the package using the provided commands in the documentation:

`pip install lifelines`
and
`conda install -c conda-forge lifelines`

Both times the installation is marked as successfull. When I run Python within the terminal I can import the lifelines package without problem. However whem I import it on a jupyter notebook it yields a **ModuleNotFoundError**.

The base environment I use does not contain the lifelines package when I verify its contents using the Anaconda Navigator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jupyter notebooks are run on Anaconda Powershell, and so are the environments and packages.

Installing on the Windows Powershell will never work. Running the `conda install -c conda-forge lifelines` in the Anaconda shell solved the issue.

So silly, yet so time consuming it is worth sharing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a issue like this, `python3 -m pip install <package_name>` solved it for me. Use `python -m pip install <package_name>` for Python2.